# R package installation in ubuntu

Tags: r, r-package

Something of a newbie here.  I've been working in R for windows and have recently moved to ubuntu, ("Hardy Heron" I think).  I'm also not a linux guy.  Anyway.  I'm tring to install the "diptest" package.  I ran the command

```
install.packages("diptest")
```

and the output is:

> Installing package(s) into ‘/home/smart/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.6’
>       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   which is a little strange since I'm running R 2.12.1.  And then it hangs.

Also, if I call `library("diptest")` it says that I need to reinstall the package because it is built for R 2.6.  Is the process for reinstalling different than `install.packages`?  Thanks.  Sorry to ask such a simple question.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you installed the new R? On Ubuntu (which is debian based), you should follow these instructions : http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/  It looks very similar to a problem we ran into on our debian server after a faulty installation of R.

Answer (score 11):

Reinstalling is exactly the same procedure as installing, namely install.packages("diptest"). You might want to use the option `repos` to point to the correct repository. It seems there is going something wrong. AFAIK R uses the correct repos for the version, but it can be there's something odd going on with your installation. Make sure you followed the instructions for installing R on debian [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/).

So for my repos that would make :

```
install.packages("diptest",
   repos="http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.12")
```

You can get some information by using the command `packageStatus()`. This should also give you the repository, eg :

```
> update(packageStatus())
Number of installed packages:

                         ok upgrade unavailable
  E:/R/Library          111       1           2
  C:/R/R-2.12.2/library  26       2           0

Number of available packages (each package counted only once):

                                                              installed not installed
  http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.12        99          2791
  http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.12         3            12
```

If that is OK, you can check whether the package is actually installed :

```
"diptest" %in% installed.packages()
```

if yes, you can check with `old.packages()` whether you can find a newer version.

```
> old.packages()
         Package    LibPath                 Installed     Built    ReposVer     
survival "survival" "E:/R/Library"          "2.36-2"      "2.12.1" "2.36-5"     
lattice  "lattice"  "C:/R/R-2.12.2/library" "0.19-17"     "2.12.2" "0.19-23"    
Matrix   "Matrix"   "C:/R/R-2.12.2/library" "0.999375-46" "2.12.2" "0.999375-49"
         Repository                                                   
survival "http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.12"
lattice  "http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.12"
Matrix   "http://www.freestatistics.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.12"
```

If that is true, you can either install a new version using

`install.packages("diptest")`

or just update all of them, using

```
update.packages()
```

HTH